# weakly $p-$summable sequences in $L_{\infty}(\Omega, \mu)$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $1\leq p<\infty$ and $(\Omega, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f_{1},\ldots,f_{m}\in L_{\infty}(\Omega, \mu)$. What is the definition of weakly $p-$summable sequences $(f_{j})_{j=1}^m$ in $L_{\infty}(\Omega, \mu)$ ?

Comment: My guess is that $\sum |x^* f_j|^p<\infty$ for each $x^*\in L_\infty^*$. But you're only considering finite sequences?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i am looking for another definition is related to the space of bounded sequences.